# Adjust a collectionViewCell's constant dynamically to use in auto layout

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, autolayout

I have a `UICollectionView` that renders cells with a `UILabel` and below that a `UIView`. The `UIView` is using a `topAnchor` with a constant of `10` to the `UILabel`.

Some cells will have a nil value for the `UILabel`. In this case I want the constant used in the `topAnchor` to be `0`.

I am able to set the constant per cell (using a `didSet` observer in the cell). The layout however I am not able to update. `view.layoutIfNeeded()` isn't doing it. Below is the code. I'm grateful for any pointers. Thanks!!

This here is in the cell class:

```
var photoMarginToTop = CGFloat()

var post: Post? {
    if post?.title != nil {
        titleLabel.text = post?.title
        photoMarginToTop = 10
        updateLayout()
    }

    if post?.title == nil {
        photoMarginToTop = 0
        updateLayout()
    }
}

func updateLayout() {
    photoView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: titleLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: photoMarginToTop).isActive = true
    photoView.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

Comment: If the label is nil then a 0 constant isn’t enough because it’s still anchored to the label, which may not exist. Regardless, for performance sake, I would not add a bunch of property observers to a collection of reusable cells if it isn’t necessary because it can get messy and glitchy. Just make two cells, one with a label and one without and dequeue the necessary one at the data source.

Answer (score 0):

layoutIfNeeded() function layouts the subviews of the view, Not the view which you passed this function. So, update the cell layout directly.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to create dynamic heights for your cells?

I would suggest you subclass `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` and follow [this tutorial by Ray Wenderlich](https://www.raywenderlich.com/164608/uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial-pinterest-2). They take random image heights and adjust the cell size accordingly.